# how to get app installation directory phone gap android

Tags: android, file, cordova

I want to store music files downloaded from server in my application installation directory. I noticed that several android phones has different path to application installationo directory.
Such as Android/data, data/data and etc.

I develop the application with phoengap. I checked their api but coudnt get a methode that return application installaitn folder path.

Can anybody help me on this?

thanks

Comment: This link might help you to find app installation directory:http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed

Comment: I checked it, It is about places that application can be located.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons, you cannot write to application install or the assets directory, instead you can write files in application data folder.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html